# Function doesn't change a global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, last.fm

Been struggling with a little problem for a while. Here, I have a function which searches for album covers via [album-cover](https://github.com/hanse/album-cover) and [Last.FM API](https://www.last.fm/api). Here's the function itself:

```js
global.url = ' '
function CoverReturn(artist_name, release_name) {
    search_covers(last_fm_api_token).search({
        artist: artist_name,
        album: release_name,
        size: 'extralarge'
    }, function(err, res) {
        res = res.replace("300x300", "1024x1024")
        url = res
    });
}
CoverReturn(...)
console.log(url)
```

The problem is that the function doesn't change the `url` variable at all (and yeah, I really need to change it). I've tried different ways to change this variable, but it just doesn't. What's the problem?

Comment: You expect the `function (err, res)` to run immediately when you call CoverReturn, but it doesn't.